# Prevent recursive locking when using SemaphoreSlim

Tags: c#

I am building a `IConcurrentMemoryCache`(which I still did not test if it works :p), but anyhow the idea is to only allow a single thread to execute e func per cache key. Here is my current implementation so far:

```
internal class ConcurrentMemoryCache : IConcurrentMemoryCache
{
    private readonly IMemoryCache _cache;
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, SemaphoreSlim> _cacheLocks = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, SemaphoreSlim>();

    public ConcurrentMemoryCache(IMemoryCache cache)
    {
        _cache = cache;
    }

    public async Task<T> GetOrCreateAsync<T>(string key, Func<ICacheEntry, Task<T>> func)
    {
        if (_cache.TryGetValue(key, out T value))
        {
            return value;
        }

        var locker = _cacheLocks.GetOrAdd(key, s => new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1));
        await locker.WaitAsync();
        try
        {
            return await _cache.GetOrCreateAsync(key, func);
        }
        finally
        {
            locker.Release();
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_cacheLocks != null && _cacheLocks.Values.Any())
        {
            var locks = _cacheLocks.Values;
            _cacheLocks.Clear();
            foreach (var semaphoreSlim in locks)
            {
                semaphoreSlim?.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is simple, use a dictionary to store semaphore slims and then lock based on the key. At least from my unit tests it works fine so far but there is an edge case that does not work. If you try to resolve an object with the same key in a recursive pattern it will block the thread forever.

Check the unit test below:

```
[Test]
public void Test() 
{ 
    //Arrange
    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
    var ex = Assert.ThrowsAsync<Exception>(() => _cache.GetOrCreateAsync("myKey", async entry =>
    {
        var myTime = await _cache.GetOrCreateAsync("myKey", cacheEntry => Task.FromResult(dateTime));
        return myTime;
    }));
    //Act
    //Assert
}
```

Is there any way how to detect this circular/recursive locking and throw an exception instead ?

I could do something like this:

```
if (await locker.WaitAsync(0))
{
    throw new Exception("");
}
```

But this would break other waiting threads instead!

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Store the key on first entry, and early `return` if you see the same key again?

Comment: You should probably test your code before posting on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Dortimer thanks for trying to help. The code is not completely untested. As I said is unit-tested and works fine for my use case. But as you might know you can not just publish a library for public usage if there is distinct use case that might break the application. Cheers